# How are Lagrangian mechanics equivalent to Newtonian mechanics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I didn't study Lagrangian mechanics yet but I did study Newtonian mechanics, and someone said to me that later we would study analytic mechanics (which contain Lagrangian mechanics) and that it contain some equations that are equivalent to Newton's laws  but are more fundamental. I want just one single example of this without complicated maths if possible, but I will study the core and pure thing later on.

Comment: Seems this question would be better for physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8903/2451

Answer (score 9):

The Euler-Lagrange equation: $$\frac{\mathrm d\mathcal{L}}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm d\mathcal{L}}{\mathrm d\dot{x}}$$ is equivalent to Newton's second law of motion which states: $$\mathbf{ F}=m\vec a.$$

---

I will not go into the pure maths way since I will only present the procedures to show that our first equation is equivalent to Newton's second law. 
The Lagrangian (denoted $\mathcal L$) is simply the kinetic energy of a body minus its potential energy which can be written as follows, $\mathcal L=1/2mv^2-\mathrm V(x)$. Now if you take the derivative of this Lagrangian w.r.t $x$ you will simply get the derivative of the potential energy $\mathrm{V}(x)$ w.r.t $x$, which is a force. So the LHS of the first equation is equivalent to the LHS of the second. 
$\dot{x}$ just means the derivative of $x$ w.r.t time, so if you differentiate the Lagrangian with respect to $\dot{x}$, which is velocity, you will get $m\dot{x}$ since $$\frac{\mathrm d\mathcal{L}}{\mathrm d\dot{x}}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\dot{x}}\frac12 mv^2-\mathrm{V}(x)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\dot{x}}\frac12 m\dot{x}^2=m\dot{x}.$$
And the derivative of the latter w.r.t time will be $m\ddot{x}$ which is of course $m\vec{a}$. So the RHS of the first equation is equivalent to the RHS of the second equation. Therefore:

$$\frac{\mathrm d\mathcal{L}}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm d\mathcal{L}}{\mathrm d\dot{x}}\iff \mathbf{ F}=m\vec a.$$

Comment: I am sitting through a course which exactly deals with this question.  I don't think the Euler-Lagrangian equations are more fundamental than Newton's laws - actually they are equivalent.  However in many cases the Euler-Lagrange equation end up much simpler to work with than Newton's laws.  They really are a genius of abstraction, and an abstraction which ends up being easier to work with than the concrete.  The next level of abstraction is Hamiltonian mechanics.  But personally I think the Euler-Lagrangian approach is the best.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thanks for your comment. Cheers!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Newton's laws and the E-L equations are are only mathematically equivalent if you presuppose a Newtonian framework (e.g., assumptions about the particular form of the Lagrangian). The E-L equations generalize quite naturally to relativistic and quantum regimes, whereas Newton's laws notoriously do not, so I think we can very justifiably identify Lagrangian mechanics as the more fundamental.

Comment: @DavidH Great comment.  It was actually a bit of an "ahah" moment for me when I thought about what you wrote.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Very good! It's tangentially tied up with a number of aspects of the Lagrangian method I found to be utterly mysterious until well into grad school, and that I wish someone had explained to me sooner. For instance, if you start with NL's you can easily derive that the Lagrangian must have the form, $L(v,x)=K(v)-U(x)$. But when starting from the other direction, we're told from on high to just assume $L$ separates into a simple sum of kinetic term plus potential, and wondered what motivates this. And the answer is turns out to be nothing other than it leads to NL's!!!

Comment: What about the Q term in Euler-Lagrange Equations? I mean this argument is valid just for conservative systems.

Comment: @H.R. yes it is...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example since you requested one in your post. Consider a pendulum with length $\ell$ and bob mass $m$. Then the energies of the system are
\begin{align}
V &= mg\ell(1 - \cos(\theta))\\
T &= \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2
\end{align}
Now to use the Euler Lagrange equations we need a generalized coordinate. In this case we will take $\theta$ as our generalized coordinate and assume a small angle approximation. Then with the small angle approximation $\sin(\theta) \approx\theta$ since $\sin(\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\theta^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. Therefore, $\sin(\theta)\approx\theta = \frac{x}{\ell}$ so $x = \ell\theta$ and our potential energy is 
$$
T = \frac{1}{2}m(\ell\dot{\theta})^2
$$
From the first answer, we know that 
$$
\mathcal{L} = T - V = \frac{1}{2}m(\ell\dot{\theta})^2 - mg\ell(1 - \cos(\theta))
$$
Now let's apply the EL equations
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\theta} &= -mg\ell\sin(\theta)\\
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{\theta}} &= m\ell^2\dot{\theta}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{\theta}} &= m\ell^2\ddot{\theta}\\
m\ell^2\ddot{\theta} + mgl\sin(\theta) &= 0
\end{align}
Again applying our small angle approximations, we have 
$$
m\ell^2\ddot{\theta} + mgl\sin(\theta) \approx m\ell^2\ddot{\theta} + mgl\theta = \ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{\ell}\theta =0
$$
Now work out the solution in Newtonian Mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the Lagrangian approach is indeed more fundamental than Newton's laws. The reason for this is that the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion do indeed reduce to the ones that one gets from Newton's laws; they are also simpler and in general, easier to work out, but that is not the point. The point is that the Euler-Lagrange equations come from the principle of minimal action, which is a fundamental one, equivalent to the principle that dictates that every physical system will tend to minimize its free energy. Furthermore, it is in this approach (Euler-Lagrange) that through a theorem by Emmy Noether we know that the presence of symmetries leads to conserved quantities, which in turn, has led to fundamental discoveries in quantum field theory (read gauge theories).